# What's the best practice to manage Facebook API secret in a team environment

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

We are using Facebook Graph API in our company website and the API secret is shared among the developer team for testing as well as being used in production. The problem is that when a developer leaves the company, we have to change the Facebook API secret to prevent possible security breach. It does not seem to me that Facebook API allows to create multiple API secrets. I was wondering how other team address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can store this SecretKey into the database in some encrypted form.

Now you can provide the db access to you team with decryption algorithms, so who have that algorithm can only access the secret and decryption is only known to you which can resolve your stuff.

Comment: But you still have to distribute the decryption key to the team members for them to be able to decrypt the encrypted SecretKey, don't you? Then it does not really resolve the problem.

Comment: You can store decryption algorithm on web server in a single web method (web service)and give access to that method to many client , so nobody can know your logic of encryption and decryption they just use it.